# convert dataframe index from string mmm/dd to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Sep-13    333  
Sep-14    333  
Sep-15    311  
Sep-16    311  
Sep-17    317  
Sep-18    300  
Sep-19    311  
Sep-20    306  
Sep-21    328  
Sep-22    328  
Sep-23    333  
Sep-24    339  
Sep-25    328  
Sep-26    317  
Sep-27    278  
Sep-28    294  
Sep-29    283  
Sep-30    278  
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

I'm trying to convert the index to datetime format using the  following command:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

getting the following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-04-01 00:00:00
```

How can that index converted to datetime format?

Comment: What year do you want?

Comment: no year, just day-month

Comment: Then that's not a `datetime`. You need at least a year-month-day to properly define a datetime. Even if you try to convert it with the proper format `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%b-%d')` it's going to coerce the year to 1900.

Comment: understand... then what would be the propper numeric format to put this into a chart?

Comment: Set the date column as the index `df.set_index('date', inplace=True)` and then plot the dataframe `df.plot(kind='bar')` or leave the dataframe as is do `plt.bar('date', 'value', data=df)`.